# Trying to find the NPV

Tags: analysis

A popular movie actress has been offered a two-year contract. She can either accept 2,350,000 dollars now or accept monthly amounts of 100,000 dollars payable at the end of each month. If money can be invested at 3.5% compounded monthly, compute the net present value of each option and decide which is the better option for the actress and by how much?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Well I'm basically self teaching myself right now so i was using my calculator and tried using the CF and NPV functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We calculate present value by working backward from the future value: if $i$ is the monthly interest rate and it's compounded every month for $m$ months, then $FV = PV(1+i)^m$. Then we just add these up over for each month - that is, for a payment of amount $PMT$, we have $NPV =  \frac{PMT}{1+i} + \frac{PMT}{(1+i)^2} + ... + \frac{PMT}{(1+i)^m}$. This is a geometric partial sum, which we know how to compute quickly - we get $NPV = PMT\frac{1-(1+i)^{-m}}{i}$. In this case, I calculated that the present value of the monthly payment option was \$1,605,836.76.

On a side note, \$100,000 monthly for two years is \$2,400,000. That's only \$50,000 more, or about 2.1% more than the bulk payment option, so I would have right off the bat said I'd take the immediate payment knowing I could invest it. Of course, then I wouldn't get to practice calculating...

I'm assuming that you meant 3.5% was the monthly rate, not the annual rate. If it was the annual rate, you'd just have to divide it to find the monthly rate.

Comment: how would i get $2,314,668.96 as the NPV? thats what I'm being told is the correct answer.

Comment: I couldn't tell if you meant that 3.5% was the monthly or annual rate, as I noted above, where I computed the value for a 3.5% monthly rate. If that's the annual rate, however, you're splitting the interest up into twelve parts throughout the year, so you'd divide 3.5% by 12. In the equations, you'd just replace 3.5% (that is, .035) by 3.5%/12 (or .035/12). I used that number instead, tried it again, and got $2,314,668.96 as you were looking for. I see you're new here, too - if you've found the explanation you were looking for, please don't forget to mark it as accepted. Thank you!